# Selecting number of features for RFE model in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with more than 120 features, and I want to use RFE for selecting which features / column names I should use.
I have a problem because RFE is very slow. My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

full_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

x = full_df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = full_df.iloc[:,-1]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

model = LogisticRegression(solver ='lbfgs')

for i in range(1,120):

    rfe = RFE(model, i)
    fit = rfe.fit(x_train, y_train)
    acc = fit.score(x_test, y_test)

    print(acc)
    print(fit.support_)
```

My problem is this: `rfe = RFE(model, i)`. I do not know what's the best number for `i`. That's why I put it in `for i in range(1,120)`. Is there any better way to do this? is there any better function in `scikit learn` that can help me determine the number of features and names of those features?

Because this took to long, I changed my approach, and I want to see what you think about it, is it good / correct approach.

First I did `PCA`, and I found out that each column participates with around 1-0.4%, except last 9 columns. Last 9 columns participate with less than 0.00001% so I removed them. Now I have 121 features.

```
pca = PCA()
fit = pca.fit(x)
```

Then I split my data into train and test (with 121 features).

Then I used `SelectFromModel`, and I tested it with 4 different classifiers. Each classifier in `SelectFromModel` reduced the number of columns. I chosed the number of column that was determined by classifier that gave me the best accuracy:

```
model = SelectFromModel(clf, prefit=True)
#train_score = clf.score(x_train, y_train)
test_score = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
column_res = model.transform(x_train).shape
```

End finally I used 'RFE'. I have used number of columns that i get with 'SelectFromModel'.

```
rfe = RFE(model, number_of_columns)
fit = rfe.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = fit.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Is this a good approach, or I did something wrong?
Also, If I got the biggest accuracy in `SelectFromModel` with one classifier, do I need to use the same classifier in `RFE`?

Comment: Did you try RFECV (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV)? This class allows to choose the optimal  number of features based on CV. Thus, it is slower than a single run of `RFE`, but is faster than your current solution as long as `cv < 120`. If that is still slow, you can play around with `step`. And yes, you can use `.score`, if you configure scoring of RFECV to be accuracy

Comment: With `RFE` I can choose optimal number of features, i can say `rfe = RFE(model, 10)` but I want to know is the optimal number of features 5, 10 or 55 etc.
The code that I wrote gives me the best feature / features depending on`i` value, but thats very slow

Comment: Why do you want to do feature elimination in the first place?

Comment: Beacuse Im learning feature selection, and because i have more than 100 unnamed columns

Comment: @taga `RFE` always reduces down to the specified number of features. Those are the optimal set of arbitrary fixed size of features that gives the best metrics. As you said, with `RFE` you can not find the *optimal* size of the feature set. In contrast, `RFECV` also finds this optimum (by using the evaluation metric on the CV). The number parameter in the case of `RFECV` is the *minimum* of the feature set considered. But it can stop sooner

Comment: Is this a good approach: First I do `PCA` so that I can remove some features, then I do `SelectFromModel` to get optimal number of columns, and then do the `RFE` with number of columns that I get with `SelectFromModel` ?

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi I know that, but I want to find what number of features is the best.  Can I do this, First I do `PCA` so that I can remove some features, then I do `SelectFromModel` to get optimal number of columns, and then do the `RFE` with number of columns that I get with `SelectFromModel` ?